# how to convert pointcloud to laser scan in ros indigo

Tags: ros, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ros indigo.I want to convert point cloud to laser scan data.I used freenect to collect kinect data( using kinect Xbox 360).Now I want to convert this data to lasercan data to construct 2D map.I read that we can use depthimage_to_laserscan package.I used the command `rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw`,but it is not showing anything.I am new to ROS and someone please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224463/how-to-convert-pointcloud-to-laser-scan-in-ros-indigo/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-15**:
thank you......i solved that problem

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2016-04-10**:
hey David can you plz tell me how did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you confirmed if the depth image is generating correctly or not? Try this to view the depth image `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image_raw`

---

Originally posted by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) with karma: 71 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0